# SQL Error - The identifier that starts with..........is too long. Maximum lenght is 128

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL query which is returning back error message

> The identifier that starts with 'CASE WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' THEN >vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE
>                                     WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRTY <> 'AUT' THEN vwPxPaxWe'
>   is too long. Maximum length is 128.
>
> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Procedure vwRBARpt_AJ, Line 168
>   The identifier that starts with 'CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Int. – Inbound >Then vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA' is too long. Maximum length is 128."

Here's the SQL query:

```
CASE 
   WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Dom. - NAT' 
     THEN [CASE 
              WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' THEN vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE
              WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRTY <> 'AUT' THEN vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA
              ELSE COALESCE (vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE, vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA, AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) ]
   ELSE 
      [CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = Int. – Inbound 
              THEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA
              ELSE COALESCE(vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA, AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC)]
END AS SALES_AREA_DESC_2
```

Comment: Square brackets `[]` are used to delimit identifiers in SQL Server. You probably want parentheses `()`.

Comment: Also, the "inner" `CASE` statements are missing `END` keywords

Answer (score 1):

It took me formatting your code to realize it, but you need parentheses and not square brackets surrounding your cases. As you have it, it's trying to find a column/table/whatever that's named "[...your code...]", which is certainly too long.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwRailBookingAgentRpt_AJ_Latest, Line 157
The multi-part identifier "PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwRailBookingAgentRpt_AJ_Latest, Line 159
The multi-part identifier "PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRTY" could not be bound.

Comment: That's a different question. Are you sure you're running in the correct database context? You aren't in master or anything like that?

Comment: Thanks i will post it seperately

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like below. Use `()` to separate the `CASE`. `[]` is used for identifires; like if you are using reserve word as column names or if your column names have spaces in it then to delimit them.

```
CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Dom. - NAT' THEN 
(CASE WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY = 'AUT' THEN vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE

 WHEN PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRTY <> 'AUT' THEN vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA

ELSE COALESCE (vw_POSTCODE.POSTCODE,vwPxPaxWeb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC) 
)

ELSE 
(CASE WHEN AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC = 'Int. – Inbound' Then vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA

ELSE COALESCE( vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA,AG_AGENTS.SALES_AREA_DESC)
)
END AS SALES_AREA_DESC_2
```

Comment: I have modified my query a bit as there was error in the above query. The new SQl query is as below

Comment: Now i am getting error message Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwRailBookingAgentRpt_AJ_Latest, Line 157
The multi-part identifier "PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRY" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwRailBookingAgentRpt_AJ_Latest, Line 159
The multi-part identifier "PX_PAXWEB.COUNTRTY" could not be bound.

Comment: That's cause you are not using correct database/table/column name which I can't say for sure without sufficient information from you. Also, that's a separate question which you should consider posting separately.

Comment: Thanks i will post it seperately