# SQL Error - Identifier that starts with .. is too long - preview works in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssms

Currently I'm encountering an issue when loading (a selection of) data residing inside an Oracle database to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

When running the following query in SQL Developer (Oracle) it runs fine:

```
SELECT
        BOT.BOT_ID,
        BOT.BOT_VOLGNUMMER,
        (SELECT
            B.BEW_WAARDE_NUM 
        FROM
            V_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDEN B 
        WHERE
            B.BOT_ID = BEW.BOT_ID 
            AND B.BET_ID = 740000000000638 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_INGANG <= TRUNC(B.SYSDATE) 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_TM >= TRUNC(B.SYSDATE)),
        (SELECT
            BAW.BAW_ANTWOORD 
        FROM
            V_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDEN B 
        INNER JOIN
            BAE_ANTWOORDEN BAW 
                ON BAW.BAW_ID = B.BAW_ID 
        WHERE
            B.BOT_ID = BEW.BOT_ID 
            AND B.BET_ID = 740000000000671 
            AND 1 = 1 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_INGANG <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_TM >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)) 
    FROM
        V_INFO_OBJECT_DUMMY BEW 
    INNER JOIN
        V_INFO_OBJECTEN_ALL BOT 
            ON BEW.BOT_ID = BOT.BOT_ID 
    WHERE
        1 = 1 
        AND (
            BOT.BOE_ID IN (
                1100000039
            ) 
            AND BOT.BOS_STATUS IN (
                'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5', 'Cat6', 'Cat7'
            )
        ) 
    ORDER BY
        BOT.BOT_VOLGNUMMER ASC
```

When I use this query in the import wizard (in SSMS), it says the SQL statement is valid. When I continue and preview the data (in the next window in the wizard), it also gives me a correct preview of the data (similar to SQL Developer). 
However, when I execute the statement, it gives an error, namely:

```
Error: Preparation SQL Task 1: The identifier that starts with '(SELECTBEW_WAARDE_NUMFROMV_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDENBWHEREB.BOT_ID=BEW.BOT_IDANDB.BET_ID=740000000000638ANDB.BEW_DATUM_INGANG<=TRUNC(S' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I looked up several other similar questions, however most of them involve the (mis)use of double quotes instead of single quotes, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603993/the-identifier-that-starts-with-is-too-long-maximum-length-is-128/26847434). Or they involve (mis)use of square brackets instead of parentheses, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793438/sql-error-the-identifier-that-starts-with-is-too-long-maximum-lenght).

I guess the error has something to do with (final) column names being too long? Is there a way to overcome this? Or is the error caused by something else?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: You don't migrate to SSMS. SSMS is just an application used to interact with SQL Server. It would be like someone saying they are migrating from PostgreSQL to Oracle Developer Studio.

Comment: Where are all the spaces in your query? `SELECTBEW_WAARDE_NUMFROMV...`

Comment: Add some aliases to columns that you get from subqueries ` ...TRUNC(B.SYSDATE)) AS BEW_WAARDE_NUM ,`

Comment: 1. This statement cannot pass parsing as it has TRUNC which is not a recognized built-in function name. 2. Your sofware does not support subqueries in SELECT clause and tries to interpret them as column names, add them using cross apply, even if even this can be unsupported by your migration program

Comment: What if all the `TRUNC(B.SYSDATE)` is replaced by standard SQL `CAST(B.SYSDATE AS DATE)`?

Comment: @Larnu my bad, wrong use of words.

Comment: @juergend The error message does not display spaces, they are present in the query though

Comment: @LukStorms When applying your suggestion, the SQL statement can't be parsed (error message). "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: @DenisRubashkin thanks! That solved my problem, partly however. A next issue that now occurs, is that the column "BEW_WAARDE_NUM" has a precision of 38, therefore a scale of 38, but the error that occurs is: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type". Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Update:  I found this problem arose due to the data-type. The default was 'numeric', setting it to int (which the values in the column are) resolved this.

Comment: @D.vdV.  Nice that your problem got resolved. But since it seems you're trying to more familiar with ms sql server, here's a tip.  It also supports [OUTER APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your projection contains scalar subqueries. That is probably fine (I believe SQL Server supports them) but you haven't given them column aliases.

Now identifier `SELECTBEW_WAARDE_NUMFROMV_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDENBWHEREB.BOT_ID=BEW.BOT_IDANDB.BET_ID=740000000000638ANDB.BEW_DATUM_INGANG<=TRUNC(S` is the start of your scalar cursor without spaces. So I'm guessing SSMS requires columns to be named and, as you haven't provided an alias, is generating them using **the whole cursor statement**. Which is longer than the permitted 128 characters and hence the error.

(It seems SQL Developer is clever enough to apply a `substring()` to the generated names.)

Anyway, if my guess is correct all you need to do is provide those columns with  aliases, such as

```
SELECT
        BOT.BOT_ID,
        BOT.BOT_VOLGNUMMER,
        (SELECT
            B.BEW_WAARDE_NUM 
        FROM
            V_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDEN B 
        WHERE
            B.BOT_ID = BEW.BOT_ID 
            AND B.BET_ID = 740000000000638 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_INGANG <= TRUNC(B.SYSDATE) 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_TM >= TRUNC(B.SYSDATE)
       ) as bew_waarde_num,
       (SELECT
            BAW.BAW_ANTWOORD 
        FROM
            V_BAE_ELEMENT_WAARDEN B 
        INNER JOIN
            BAE_ANTWOORDEN BAW 
                ON BAW.BAW_ID = B.BAW_ID 
        WHERE
            B.BOT_ID = BEW.BOT_ID 
            AND B.BET_ID = 740000000000671 
            AND 1 = 1 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_INGANG <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
            AND B.BEW_DATUM_TM >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       ) as baw_antwoord, 
     ....
```

---

There may be other issues with porting Oracle queries to run on SQL Server, such as the use of Oracle specific `trunc(SYSDATE)` instead of their MSSQL analogues `CONVERT (date, GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me overcome the specified error above, however, as also noting above in one of my comments, a new error occurred:  the column "BEW_WAARDE_NUM" has a precision of 38, therefore a scale of 38, but the error that occurs is: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type". Any thoughts on this?

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Either way I'm afraid I don't know enough about SSMS to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found this problem arose due to the data-type. The default was 'numeric', setting it to int (which the values in the column are) resolved this.